# append constant as key to an array to create key value pair on statemachine input

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

My input is:

```
{
   field1: “abc”,
   field2 : [ “obj1", “obj2"]
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
   field1: “abc”,
   field3: [
     { id: “obj1"},
     { id: “obj2”}
   ]
}
```

I want to do this manipulation using parameters of statemachine. I do not want to use map or choice to iterate over array. Is there any way to achieve this?

Ive already tried

```
"Targets.$" : [ {"id.$": "$.field2"}]
```

but the output is :

```
{
"Targets.$": [
    {
      "id": [
        "obj1",
        "obj2"
      ]
    }
  ],
}
```